# Deploy JavaFX application to Mac from Windows

Tags: java, windows, macos, deployment

I cant seem to find anything concrete on this subject.

Is it even possible?

I really need help with this.

I have the application ready and have packaged it as a .exe installer already and it works fine but the "customer" this is for also have mac OS.

Im using Netbeans IDE

Thanks in advance

JohnBanana

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible. You have to be on a Mac to build and package the app for a Mac.

Comment: Could I do it on a virtualBox?

Comment: I've never tried it but if you have a virtual Mac box this should work.